# Babel failing to compile decorator syntax, despite correct plugin

Tags: reactjs, plugins, webpack, decorator, babeljs

Trying to use decorators in my React project, and even though I have installed the babel plugin that enables them, and referenced the plugin in `.babelrc`, I'm still getting a syntax error in my console.

**package.json**

```
// ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.16.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7"
  }
// ...
```

**.babelrc** - I previously had the `transform-object-rest-spread` plugin installed, so have just extended the `plugins` array:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread", "transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```

And the console error, in full (just in case):

```
BabelLoaderError: SyntaxError: Decorators are not officially supported yet in 6.x pending a proposal update.
However, if you need to use them you can install the legacy decorators transform with:

npm install babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy --save-dev

and add the following line to your .babelrc file:

{
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}

The repo url is: https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: post your webpack config as well

Comment: Oops, just as I received your response I solved it :) See answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had included the plugin in `.babelrc` but not `webpack.config.js` (as azium pointed out).

When I included this, it worked:

```
// ...
query: {
   plugins: [ 'transform-decorators-legacy' ]
}
// ...
```

Hope that helps in case anyone else runs into this problem :)

Comment: So which takes precedence? The `.babelrc` file or the babel config in `webpack`? Does it merge them?

Comment: Ooh, Interesting. It looks like we could add a `bablerc: false` to webpack, in which case it will _really_ only use the webpack config. Apart from that, still not sure what occurs! https://gist.github.com/rmoorman/94eeed830942758e218d92f15ce58d88